# MS SQL locking for update

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am implementing a competition where there might be a lot of simultaneous entries. I am collecting some user data, which I am putting in one table called entries. I have another table of pre-generated unique discount codes in a table called discountCodes. I am then assigning one to each entry. I thought I would do this by putting a entry id in the discountCodes table.

As there may be a lot of concurrent users I think I should select the first unassigned row and then assign the entry id to that row. I need to make sure between picking an unassigned row and adding the entry id that another thread doesn't find the same row.

What is the best way of ensuring that the row doesn't get assigned twice?

Comment: Can you add a `falg` to table so you can mark as soon as one pick the each row?

Comment: @huMptyduMpty Problem with that is if the users select it at the same time, they could select the same one before the flag is set.

Comment: @Elias: Yes but you can avoid using the same row twise?

Comment: See [Using tables as Queues](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/).

Comment: Rather than pre-generate the discount codes could you not generate one at the point where you store the user data?

Comment: Why not just use a transaction to prevent others from changing the records you are updating and then implement some concurrency (I like to increment a number by 1 in high transaction situations) to prevent changes to stale data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something can be done like

*The following example sets the TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL for the session. For each Transact-SQL statement that follows, SQL Server holds all of the shared locks until the end of the transaction.* **Source:MSDN**

```
USE databaseName;
GO
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;
GO
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
GO
SELECT * 
    FROM Table1;
GO
SELECT * 
    FROM Table2;
GO
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
GO
```

Read more [SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend building a bridge table instead of having the `EntryId` in the `DiscountCodes` table with an `EntryId` and a `DiscountCodeId`.  Place a `Unique Constraint` on both of those fields.

This way your entry point will encounter a constraint violation when it tries to enter a duplicate.

Comment: Why having a bridge table for that? You could create a unique index on existing `discountCodes.entryId` just as well (and in fact this should be done anyway).

Comment: @Quassnoi `DiscountCodes` is updated, not inserted against, because the table is prefilled.  Your solution would not stop a `DiscountCode.EntryId` from being overwritten, aka, used twice.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH    e AS
        (
        SELECT  *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) rn
        FROM    entries ei
        WHERE   NOT EXISTS
                (
                SELECT  NULL
                FROM    discountCodes dci
                WHERE   dci.entryId = ei.id
                )
        ),
        dc AS
        (
        SELECT  *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) rn
        FROM    discountCodes
        WHERE   entryId IS NULL
        )
UPDATE  dc
SET     dc.entryId = e.id
FROM    e
JOIN    dc
ON      dc.rn = e.rn
```

Comment: Will this automatically lock, i.e. can another thread also select the same row between the selects and the update running, if you run these simultaneously?

Comment: @SteveTemple: yes it will. As long as another session would try to read a `discountCodes` record already updated but not yet committed (which is required by the `NOT EXISTS` part), it would get locked.

Answer (score 0):

I would just put an `IDENTITY` field on each table and let the corresponding entry match the corresponding discountCode - i.e. if you have a thousand discountCodes up front, your identity column in the discountCodes table will range from 1 to 1000.  That will match your first 1 to 1000 entries.  If you get more than 1000 entries, just add one discountCode per additional entry.

That way SQL Server handles all the problematic "get the next number in the sequence" logic for you.

Comment: `IDENTITY` is not guaranteed to be consecutive.

Comment: @Quassnoi that's interesting, except for the case where you were to delete a record, or declare your identity to increment by anything other than 1, or fiddle with it in any way, in what context could the identity not be consecutive?

Comment: It is unless you purposefully set the increment to something other than 1 or you delete rows from the table.

Comment: @DanWierenga - No it isn't. Rolled back inserts are another common cause. On SQL Server 2012 restarting the service leaves hefty gaps as well.

Comment: @MartinSmith - wow, I'd never noticed that a rollback increments the identity counter.  Good to know, thanks!

Comment: @DanWierenga: strictly speaking, a `ROLLBACK` does not increment the identity counter, it just does not roll it back to its previous state (unlike the table data).

Answer (score 0):

You can try and use [sp_getapplock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823%28SQL.90%29.aspx) and synchronize the write operation, just make sure it locks against the same hash, like

```
DECLARE @state    Int

BEGIN TRAN

-- here we're using 1 sec's as time out, but you should determine what the min value is for your instance
EXEC @state = sp_getapplock 'SyncIt', 'Exclusive', 'Transaction', 1000

-- do insert/update/etc...

-- if you like you can be a little verbose and explicit, otherwise line below shouldn't be needed
EXEC sp_releaseapplock 'SyncIt', 'Transaction'

COMMIT TRAN
```